# Magento 1 : Removing spaces from column data in collection

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

i am fetching a product collection and i want to use like condition on custom attribute but the problem is that while using like condition i want to remove all white space contain in my custom attribute value.

i have already tried

```
    $psku = 'some_sku';
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_product->addFieldToFilter(str_replace(' ', '', 'simple_skus_map'), 
    array(array('like' => '%,'.$psku.',%'),
    array('like' => '%,'.$psku),
    array('like' => $psku.',%'),
    array('like' => $psku)
   ));
```

// simple_skus_map : (my custom attribute has data like one,    two,   three   ,four). and i want the following code should fetch all the product which simple_skus_map contains any of the above mentioned word(i.e one/two/three/four) 
NOTE: noticed? i have spaces in my custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for custom attribute you can do as following, hence it will remove white space from your custom attribute value and match the given/post data

```
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_product->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('trimmed_simple_skus_map', 
    'REPLACE({{simple_skus_map}},\' \',\'\')','simple_skus_map');
    $_product->addFieldToFilter('trimmed_simple_skus_map', [
    'finset' => [$psku]
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The query as you supplied can perform slow, as it uses like with wildcards. You can use the [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) functionality.

Luckily magento supports this as well:

```php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// Trim spaces, 'save to column' trimmed_simple_skus_map
$_product->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('trimmed_simple_skus_map', 'REPLACE(sku,\' \',\' \')', 'simple_skus_map');

// Find in trimmed set
$_product->addFieldToFilter('trimmed_simple_skus_map', [
        'finset' => [$psku]
    ]
);
```

Comment: hello Paul, Thanx for you help,

i wanted to filter my custom attribute so i just modified your code and got the result as required.

Here is my code:

        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $_product->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('trimmed_simple_skus_map', 
        'REPLACE({{simple_skus_map}},\' \',\'\')','simple_skus_map');
        $_product->addFieldToFilter('trimmed_simple_skus_map', [
        'finset' => [$psku]]
        );

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution, with direct SQL queries. 
here is the php code:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    $q_find_blank = "SELECT *FIELD_NAME* FROM simple_skus_map WHERE *FIELD_NAME* LIKE '% %';  ";
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($q_find_blank); //get all field with a blank space

    foreach ($results as $result){ //set all the fields in array and removes the blanks
        $result = explode(' ',$result);
        $no_blanks_fields[] = implode("",$result);
    }

    echo print_r($no_blanks_fields);

    foreach ($no_blanks_fields as $no_blanks_field){ //replace them in the database field
        echo $no_blanks_field . "<br>";
        $q_update = "UPDATE simple_skus_map set *FIELD_NAME* = ".$no_blanks_field." WHERE *condition referencing the right field to his value*";
        $writeConnection->query($q_update);
    }
```

this is simply, not very high performance, but works.
Just remember when you write data make sure to set the correct value in the correct fields (you can maybe creating a temporary support table, with  |field|id| ).

This will remove your blanks from the selected field, and replace them with a non blanks value(or whatever you want to implode them with, just check the implode function).

"test field blanks"  =>   "testfieldsblanks"